# IC 555 timer to provide oscillation for high amp electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, 555

I am using a self-built electromagnet in my project that consumes 9.0 amps at supplied voltage of 12 VDC. I don't mind even if amps goes high. The power supply I am using can provide up to 30 amps. I have to experiment with providing an oscillating power supply to electromagnet.

I want to use IC 555 timer for that purpose. But IC 555 timers that I searched appear to have output 200 mA. Is there any 555 timer that provides high current what I need OR is it possible to use same 555 timer with some external equipment for that. Any sources or tutorial for that will also be very helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with using a separate driver?

Comment: We've [already discussed](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/97161/11683) using an H-brdige driver for your project. Why would you abandon that?

Comment: @DaveTweed: That is not abandoned. These are two separate things.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Can you please provide some source/tutorial for that. I have not found that in my search for oscilating power supply.

Comment: The H-bridge driver discussed in your other question is the component that converts a 555 timer (providing the low-current oscillating signal) and your DC power supply (providing the steady high current) into a high current oscillating power supply.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: thank you very much. So I continue with that question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: if you may find some time, can you please comment on my other question bec Andy aka has shown concerns on using an H-Bridge i.e. driver.

Comment: If this is [solved], the solution should be in an answer, and that answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a 555 timer that can drive 9 amperes. However, a 555 can drive a [transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor) which can drive 9A.

Comment: OK, that is very nice. Can you please put here a link of such a circuit/tutorial.

Comment: @enterprize I already did. The linked Wikipedia article not only demonstrates the basic use of a transistor, but tells you about the different kinds, history, construction, underlying physics, and links you to dozens more concepts you should study.

Comment: thank you very much, I have already read that and many others about transistors. I can & will search more based on your answer about this specific problem. Basically I ask bec you may already have some very good links to one.

Comment: @enterprize Google works by seeing what links people have. If you want to get a consensus on what most people think a good link for *some topic* is, Google is exactly that.